# FTP over SSL, FTPS TLS not working - Rejecting data connection - Only is allowed

Tags: tls1.2, winscp, filezilla, ftps

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.445 Read 16 bytes

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.459 200 'TYPE' OK.

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.459 PASV

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 TLS connect: SSL negotiation finished successfully

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 TLS connect: SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 Read 49 bytes

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 227 Entering Passive Mode (194,108,117,16,4,20)

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 MLSD

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 Connecting to 194.108.117.16:1044 ...

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.554 Connection pending

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.664 Read 38 bytes

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.664 150 Opening 'ASCII' data connection.

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.664 Data connection opened

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.664 TLS layer changed state from none to connected

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 Read 135 bytes

< **2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 425-Rejecting data connection from xx.xx.xx.xx1 (only xx.xx.xx.2 is allowed)**.

< 2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 425 Closing data connection; transfer not started.

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 Destroying data socket on error

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 Could not retrieve directory listing

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 Got reply 4 to the command 2

. 2024-03-06 19:45:28.774 Session upkeep

Now it says Rejecting data connection from **xx.xx.xx.xx1** (only **xx.xx.xx.xx2** is allowed) the IP addresses mentioned are different IP addresses

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).